# Ansible accumulating dictionaries in array fact via with_items

Tags: ansible

I have the following task (and a debug task):

```
- name: get list of error logs
  set_fact:
    centralised_logs: "{{ centralised_logs | default([]) | union([{'name': '{{ item }} error log'}])}}"
  with_items:
    - "one"
    - "two"
    - "three"

- debug: msg="{{ centralised_logs }}"
```

I'd expect the centralised_logs fact to accumulate an array of dictionaries that contain the interpolated strings in the union statement, but instead, I get the following (note that it works for the second and third items, but not the first):

```
TASK [nginx : get list of error logs] ******************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=one)
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=two)
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=three)

TASK [nginx : debug] ***********************************************************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "[{'name': u'two error log'}, {'name': u'three error log'}, {'name': u'{{ item }} error log'}]: 'item' is undefined"}
```

Why is the first value failing to be interpolated correctly?

Ansible version 2.1.0.0.

Comment: The square brackets `[]` mark the expression `[{'name': '{{ item }} error log'}]` as a list member, but the `union` filter operates on `lists`. So my guess would be that Ansible does not recoginse the expression as a list. I also don't understand why it works at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that you try to use a the {{ variable }}-notation inside of another one.

A correct example would be

```
- name: get list of error logs
  set_fact:
    centralised_logs: "{{ centralised_logs | default([]) | union([{'name': item + ' error log'}])}}"
  with_items:
    - "one"
    - "two"
    - "three"

- debug: msg="{{ centralised_logs }}"
```

This produces the following output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "name": "one error log"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "two error log"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "three error log"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but why is my example working for the second and third items, and not the first?

Comment: I honestly don't know why it works at all

Comment: Oh my gosh, just spent an hour trying 100 different concatenation techniques to append a dict to a list using `set_fact` and `with_items`... Using `union()` was the key, thanks for posting this answer!

Comment: @geerlingguy glad I could help you